# How to solve bittrex api error APISIGN_NOT_PROVIDED?

Tags: python, api

I'm writing a python script to check my Bittrex balances.
But I keep getting the APISIGN_NOT_PROVIDED error.
So I opened a ticket at Bittrex support and asked for an example of Python code to read balances but haven't received any reply yet.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue without importing 3rd party modules?

I'm using the following code (which I found on the internet)

```
import urllib
import requests
import json
import time
import hashlib
import hmac


nonce = str('{:10.0f}'.format(time.time()))
apikey = 'KEY HERE'
apisecret = 'SECRET HERE'
url = 'https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey=apikey'
url += '&nonce=' + str(int(time.time()))
sign = hmac.new(b'apisecret', b'url', hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
headers = {'&secret': sign}

request = requests.get(url, sign)
balance = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

print(balance)
```

Answer (score 0):

The good people of Bittrex global have answered my question, please find the functioning code below:

```
#Below is an example of a GET request using python on V1.1
import hmac
import time
import hashlib
import requests

apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
apiSecret = 'YOUR_API_SECRET'
nonce = str(round(time.time()*1000))
uri = "https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey={}&nonce={}".format(apiKey, nonce)
apiSign = hmac.new(apiSecret.encode(), uri.encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

header = {
  'apisign': apiSign
}

data = requests.get(uri, headers = header, timeout=10).json()
print (data)
```